# I can't make a spinner run for 2 seconds with nanospinner

Tags: javascript, node.js

Ok, So I'm making a game with node.js, And I imported `{ createSpinner }` from `nanospinner` and I'm trying to make it so the spinner will spin for at least **2** seconds, but when I try it, it doesn't work. Here's some example of what I've tried.

Example 1:

```
// Loading Spinner
const spinner = createSpinner('Carregando Jogo...\n').start();
await sleep()
```

By the way, here's how sleep looks like:

```
const sleep = (ms = 2000) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));
```

Example 2:

```
const spinner = createSpinner('Carregando Jogo...\n').start()

setTimeout(() => {
  spinner.success('Jogo Carregado!')
}, 1000)
```

And, here are my imports:

```
import chalk from 'chalk';
import figlet from 'figlet';
import { createSpinner } from 'nanospinner';
import inquirer from 'inquirer';
import gradient from 'gradient-string';
import chalkAnimation from 'chalk-animation';
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does it start spinning and not stop? What part is specifically not working, are there any error messages?

Comment: Well, I try to make it do it for 2 seconds, but when I try it, it just spins for like a millisecond and then stops.

Comment: Could I see the code responsible for displaying the spinner as well?

Comment: Well, The code responsible for it is `const spinner = createSpinner('Carregando Jogo...\n').start()`, This is created with nanospinner, This is the best I could do, I used `const sleep = (ms = 2000) => new Promise((r) => setTimeout(r, ms));` for making it do it for 2000 milliseconds (about 2 seconds), I don't know why it inst working, to run it I used `await sleep()`